# Hosted Source Control?

Tags: c#, .net, version-control

I'm working on a few **closed**-source projects. (Small ones.) I *don't* want to share the code of these projects. But I do want to have an easy-to-install version control system that's easily installed on my web host.

I don't have administration rights on this web host so I can't just run a setup.exe on the remote system. Basically, the only way to install something is by just creating a database and copying files to the server and maybe a bit more by using a Plesk control panel.

I can choose between two hosts: one using Linux with MySQL and the other Windows 2008/IIS7 with SQL Server 2005. The Windows host has my preference, since it provides the most disk space.

So, what options do I have? (Doesn't have to be free, although I do have a limited budget.)

---

I can have physical access to both hosts to install some additional software but it means traveling about 5.000 KM to the server room. I can also tell someone at the location of the server to install it for me, but that's quite expensive. I could just find another company to host this for me but I like my current servers/hosts. So that's why I'm looking for a solution that I can simply upload to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run Subversion on [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com) for less than $10/month.  Most of my projects are pretty small so far--I know they don't always appreciate large amounts data as non-web-accessible storage.  It is first a web host, not a file host.  However, its pretty easy to set up SVN repositories in their admin interface and then you have an easy svn+ssh connection.

Of course, since it is a web host it's easy to install [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) (they even have a 1-click install for it) or some other piece of software as well.

Comment: They also offer a one-click install of Trac, if you are interested in that. SVN and Trac are two of the reasons why I switched to Dreamhost.

Comment: @Thomas Guess we were thinking of that at the same time.

Comment: Trac looks promising! :-) It does have a few dependencies that I need to check. Another problem is the lack of a commandline to execute any installation scripts, like setpu.py as mentioned in the INSTALL document. :-(

Comment: @Workshop Alex right I don't know about command line inside Trac, but Dreamhost gives you full shell/telnet access and I'm pretty sure it can execute python scripts.

Comment: @Chet, when you install Trac, you have to execute a file called setup.py. (A Python script.) I don't have telnet/shell access to my current hosts so I can't execute this command remotely.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend both [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) and [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/). They offer different types of version control (SVN, GIT, etc.), as well as ticket management, messaging between teams, wikis, and many many other tools that I haven't gotten into yet.

I have been using Assembla and have found it to be very intuitive and offer great features, such as automatic integration between the ticketing system and the version control system. I use the free version and just hope that no one browses/steals my code until that particular project gets to the point where I should consider paying their small fee to guard it :)

Do comment on what you choose to do!

Comment: Basically, all I want is to keep backups of my code on my host, where I would be able to access it again whenever I need to. The projects are written in Visual Studio 2008 so support for the VS version control system is a big plus. And I want to host it on my own server. (To which I have limited access.)

Answer (score 2):

What is preventing you from using hosted services like:

- [Bean Stalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)
- [Project Locker](http://www.projectlocker.com/)

They offer a range of accounts including those that are free.

Comment: I have already a few sites that are hosted. Two of them are barely used so I want to use one for version control. Don't need another account for just another host.